# Detecting if input is specified discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having some trouble with detecting if the input was specified. It is just jumping to the end of the code and giving an error, skipping the `if` statements.

```
@bot.command()
async def div(ctx, left: int, right: int):
        if left == "":
                embedVar = discord.Embed(discription='.div', color=0xFA8072)
                embedVar.add_field(name="ERROR", value='Can not divide by zero', inline=False)
                return await ctx.reply(embed=embedVar)
        if right == "":
                embedVar = discord.Embed(discription='.div', color=0xFA8072)
                embedVar.add_field(name="ERROR", value='Please specify a input', inline=False)
                return await ctx.reply(embed=embedVar)

        embedVar = discord.Embed(discription='.div', color=0xFA8072)
        embedVar.add_field(name="Your answer is...", value=left / right, inline=False)
        return await ctx.reply(embed=embedVar)
```

everything except the `if` statements work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For optional arguments, you have to set a default value. For example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg1: int = None, arg2: int = None):
    if arg1 is None:
        # handle
    if arg2 is None:
        # handle
    # send
```

It might be better to use the [on_command_error event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) instead of checking if arguments were specified in every command.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the variable `left` and `right` for an empty string. Those variables however are defined as type `int`.
Try checking for `None` istead:

```
if left == None:
    # do something

if right == None:
    # do something else
```